# Limits and double integral?

Tags: integration

Determine the double integral $\int \int_{R} ye^y dxdy$, where $R$ is $1\leq x-y \leq 2,\ 1 \leq xy \leq 2$

I'm having trouble to grasp how i should think to get the limits.

$x\ne y$ becaue $1\leq xy \leq 2$.

$x$ must be atleast 1 greater then $y$ because $\ 1 \leq x-y \leq 2$.

This give me $\begin{matrix}
x &y   \\ 
2 & 1  \\ 
\end{matrix}$

Can i thefore say that the limits are $0 \leq y \leq 1, 0\leq x\leq 2y$ ?

Comment: What is R? $1\leq x-y \leq 2,\ 1 \leq x-y \leq 2$?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: These limits seems identical. Aren't you looking for $1\leq x-y \leq 2,\ 1 \leq xy \leq 2$?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to integrate over two regions. Intersection points are

$(\frac{\sqrt5 + 1} {2}, \frac{\sqrt5 - 1} {2}), (2, 1), (\sqrt3 + 1, \sqrt3 - 1), (\sqrt 2 +1, \sqrt2 - 1)$

$(\frac{-\sqrt5 + 1} {2}, \frac{-\sqrt5 - 1} {2}), (-1, -2), (-\sqrt3 + 1, -\sqrt3 - 1), (-\sqrt 2 +1, -\sqrt2 - 1)$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We have that $R$ corresponds to the strip between the lines

- $y=x-2$
- $y=x-1$

and the hyperbolas

- $y=2/x$
- $y=1/x$

[image]

One way to proceed is to find the intersection points for these region and then integrate accordingly for each part.

Comment: @user9060784 And you can take a lesson from this: Plotting is always a tremendously good idea, if you get confused!

Comment: @Milten Yes indeed at least a sketch is necessary to solve confusion.